# Attachments are 0 bytes for file sizes over 100k in Windows 2000 server IIS with ASP Classic

Tags: asp-classic, email, sendmail, cdonts

I'm using classic ASP to send an email with an attachment. It works fine for attachments under 100k, but anything larger than that gives me a zero-byte attachment.

I've tried changing messages sizes under SMTP Virtual Server Settings, but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

We were facing the same problem and resolved by following the link below

http://www.banmanpro.com/support2/File_Upload_limits.asp